# My JRuby rest-client call doesn't work when I move it to Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jruby, jrubyonrails, rest-client

I have a strange problem. I have a JRuby1.9.2/Rails 3.0.10/Ubuntu app which makes a REST call to upload some data to a web service (which itself is a Rails app on Heroku/Bamboo/MRI-1.9.2).

```
require 'rest-client' #https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client
vurl=http://myapp.heroku.com/resourcee
RestClient.post vurl, :things=>things.to_json, :content_type=>:json, :accept=>:json
```

When I run this Rails server from the command line (via "rails server"), everything works fine. But when I pack this app up in a WAR file (using "bundle exec warble war") and deploy it to a Tomcat, the same code which calls RestClient.post doesn't work at all.

I tried looking at the output in Firebug, and it didn't help any. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how Firebug would help in this case. If you wrap your rest-client call in a begin/rescue block, does it throw an exception? If you snoop network traffic with a tool like tcpdump, do you see any outgoing network connections to your Heroku app?